# Android Studio error: "Method getText() must be called from the UI Thread, currently inferred thread is worker

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

i'm creating a CRUD operation in android studio but i kept getting errors. the error is when i check the LogCat this is what they show me

> line 156-158
>   1907-1931/com.example.casquejo.loginadmin E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
>   Process: com.example.casquejo.loginadmin, PID: 1907
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing
>   doInBackground()
>     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException atcom.example.casquejo.loginadmin.NewProductActivity$CreateNewProduct.doInBackground(NewProductActivity.java:85)
>               at com.example.casquejo.loginadmin.NewProductActivity$CreateNewProduct.doInBackground(NewProductActivity.java:58)
>   atcom.example.casquejo.loginadmin.NewProductActivity$CreateNewProduct.onPreExecute(NewProductActivity.java:67)
>   atcom.example.casquejo.loginadmin.NewProductActivity$1.onClick(NewProductActivity.java:53)

can someone help me with this or can someone give an idea how to fix this` below is the code for my java class **EditProductActivity.class**

```
       package com.example.casquejo.loginadmin;

        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.List;
        import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
        import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
        import org.json.JSONException;
        import org.json.JSONObject;
        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.app.ProgressDialog;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.os.AsyncTask;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.util.Log;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.Button;
        import android.widget.EditText;

        /**
        * Created by Casquejo on 9/14/2015.
        */
        public class NewProductActivity extends Activity {
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    EditText inputName;
    EditText inputPrice;
    EditText inputDesc;

    private static String url_create_product = "http://10.0.2.2/android_connect/create_product.php";

    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add_product);

        inputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputName);
        inputPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputPrice);
        inputDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputDesc);

        Button btnCreateProduct = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCreateProduct);
        btnCreateProduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String name = inputName.getText().toString();
                String price = inputPrice.getText().toString();
                String description = inputDesc.getText().toString();
                new CreateNewProduct().execute(name, price,description);
            }
        });
    }

    class CreateNewProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(NewProductActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Creating Product..");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            String name = args[0],
                    price = args[1],
                    description = args[2];

            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("price", price));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("description", description));

            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,
                    "POST", params);

            Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AllProductsActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                }
                else {

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I would be very careful with this code, you are calling `findViewByID(...)` to get the reference to UI elements from a background thread running a runnable on the UI thread in an AsyncTask (which in itself makes no sense!) and you are not defensively using any of the UI widgets which leaves you at risk of null pointer exceptions.  I would, for example, move `txtName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputName);` and co to the `onCreate()` method

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the ide is referring to

```
  String name = txtName.getText().toString();
  String price = txtPrice.getText().toString();
  String description = txtDesc.getText().toString();
```

reading the values shouldn't be a problem, but in order to get rid of this warning/error, you can move it into the `onClick` and pass the values through `execute()`. E.g.

```
btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        String name = txtName.getText().toString();
        String price = txtPrice.getText().toString();
        String description = txtDesc.getText().toString();
        new SaveProductDetails().execute(name, price, description);
    }
});
```

when `doInBackground` is invoked, you can read those bac, through the former params, `String... args`. The three dots construct stays for varargs, and varargs can be access like an array, using the `[]` notation. In the case of the example,

`args[0]` contains the value of `name`, `args[1]` contains the value of `price` and `args[2]` contains the value of `description`.

Comment: Thank you very much! thanks for the help all of you i get it now i really can't use it in doInBackground thank you.

Comment: do you still have issues with it ?

Comment: sir i have done what you suggested in the your answer but i'm still having issues when i check the logcat the error is the onClick and also the String...args can you help me with it?

Comment: the Force close error, i can now run the application but when i go to the Adding part or the Editing part when I check the Logcat this is the errors.
at **com.example.casquejo.loginadmin.NewProductActivity$CreateNewProduct.onPreExecute(NewProductActivity.java:67)**

Comment: the error i'm getting is Force Close, i can run the whole application but i'm going for the Adding or Editing part the application is going Force Close but the data that I input is being inputted in the Database.
when i'm checking the LogCat there are errors that i found.
_ i don't know how to put pictures here so i don't know how to show you my errors._

Comment: Copy your  NewProductActivity.java, edit your question and past it

Comment: i edited it now can you please check it? thank you sir

Comment: could you tell me which line is the 85th?

Comment: The 85th line is **Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());** but i don't think that has something to do with it. but still it's still in the doInBackground

Comment: then json is null. Is the url valid ? Can you reach it with a web browser?

Comment: sir how come json is null? the url is valid sir i've checked it many times. i can reach it with web browser _http://localhost/android_connect/create_product.php_

Comment: is your endpoint returning a JSONArray instead of a JSONObject ? That's could be a reason.. try to figure it out, and if you can't open a new question

Comment: parsing problem? i never thought of it because sometimes i think it's connected with the method gettext and it can't be the PHP problems i've checked it many times but i'll try to look at it about the parsing problem. what is the meaning about opening a new question?

Answer (score 5):

You're calling `getText()` from a background thread that's spawned by the `AsyncTask`.

First fetch the text and then call your async task. Here's an example

```
new SaveProductDetails()
    .execute(txtName.getText().toString(), 
        txtPrice.getText().toString(), 
        txtDesc.getText().toString());
```

And inside of `SaveProductDetails` `doInBackground` method:

```
String name = args[0],
       price = args[1],
       description = args[2];
```

Comment: Thank you very much! thanks for the help all of you i get it now i really can't use it in doInBackground thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In an asynctask, the `doInBackground(...)` method runs in a background (non-UI) thread.  As you can see in the error given, you are not allowed to interact with UI elements from a background thread.

You can either, pass the arguments into the background thread as suggested in one of the other answers, or, you could modify your asynctask such that the UI string values are read in the `onPreExecute()` method which IS executed on the UI thread (as is the `onPostExecute()` method).

```
class SaveProductDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

private String name, price, description;

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditProductActivity.this);
    pDialog.setMessage("Saving product ...");
    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    pDialog.setCancelable(true);
    pDialog.show();

    name = txtName.getText().toString();
    price = txtPrice.getText().toString();
    description = txtDesc.getText().toString();
}

protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
    //... Use as you would before
```

I'd suggest taking a look at a blogpost such as [this](https://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/03/17/understanding-asynctask-once-and-forever/) one to understand more about AsyncTasks, how they work, how to use them including details such as which method runs on which thread.

Comment: Thank you very much! thanks for the help all of you i get it now i really can't use it in doInBackground thank you.

Comment: If one of the answers has helped you, don't forget to upvote with the arrows on the left of the answer, and mark one as accepted and correct to help others finding the question in future :)

Comment: dang! haha all of the answers helped me, i want to upvote all of them and accept it. but for the future readers all of the answers is correct these guys really helped me a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

You can read this [Using Variables on UI Thread from Worker Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18702291/using-variables-on-ui-thread-from-worker-thread) . 
In your question, you are trying to access text of TextView from background thread.
In-order to be consistent as You should not do this because their might be possibility that main thread(UI thread setting TextView at the same time). To avoid such sceneries you can to something like this:

```
class SaveProductDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{
      //create constructor and pass values of text view in it
      String textViewValue1;
      public SaveProductDetails (String textViewValue1 ){
           this.textViewValue1=textViewValue1
      }

     //other code below
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to pass the value into the execute method.
Set the name, price and description variables as global.
To get the value from EditTest on a button click code it like below:

Everytime you need to click on the button to get the JSON data.

```
btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        name = txtName.getText().toString();
        price = txtPrice.getText().toString();
        description = txtDesc.getText().toString();
        new CreateNewProduct().execute();
    }
});
```

Now name, price and description have its value whatever you entered.

Now your CreateNewProduct class seems like this:

```
class CreateNewProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(NewProductActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Creating Product..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("price", price));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("description", description));

        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,
                "POST", params);

        Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AllProductsActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
            else {

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
```

}