# Android Studio Method gettext must be called from the ui thread currently inferred thread is worker

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create a form for an application. The form contains two edittext field and a submit button. Anyway I am getting "Method getText must be called from the ui thread" error under the doInBackground().

This is my code:

```
package com.example.jinson.myapplication;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SubmitUname extends AppCompatActivity {

 private EditText editTextName;
 private EditText editTextUname;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.submit_uname);

 editTextName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editName);
 editTextUname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editUserName);


 Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
 setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
 DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
 ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
         this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
 drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
 toggle.syncState();
}

 public void insert(View view){
  String name = editTextName.getText().toString();
  String uname = editTextUname.getText().toString();
  insertToDatabase(name,uname);
 }

 private void insertToDatabase(String name, String uname){
  class SendPostReqAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
   @Override
   protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

     String paramUsername = params[0];
     String paramAddress = params[1];


       String name = editTextName.getText().toString();
       String uname = editTextUname.getText().toString();

     List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
     nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
     nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uname", uname));

     try {
      HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
      HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(
              "http://localhost/insert-db.php");
      httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

      HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

      HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();


     } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

     } catch (IOException e) {

     }

   return "success";
   }

   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
   super.onPostExecute(result);
   }
  }
 SendPostReqAsyncTask sendPostReqAsyncTask = new SendPostReqAsyncTask();
  sendPostReqAsyncTask.execute(name, uname);
  }

}
```

Android studio says that method getText() must be called from the UI Thread at the instructions: editTextName.getText().toString(); and  editTextUname.getText().toString(); Possible solutions??

I am new to this field and please give me a solution.

Comment: There is a similar questions in this forum. May be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32568340/android-studio-error-method-gettext-must-be-called-from-the-ui-thread-curre this will help you

Comment: you are creating a class within the method, you should create the SendPostReqAsyncTask outside the method. you can not access the UI component in doInBackground method. because this method is running in worker thread.

Comment: You are already passing `name` and `uname` and accessing then why do you need to use `getText().toString()` again ?

Answer (score 1):

> Android studio says that method getText() must be called from the UI Thread

Correct. If the user rotates the screen or otherwise triggers a configuration change, your activity may be gone by the time you call that code from `doInBackground()`.

> Possible solutions?

- Add a constructor to `SendPostReqAsyncTask` and pass in any values that you need into that, such as the text from the `EditText`
- Add setters to `SendPostReqAsyncTask` and pass in any values that you need into them, such as the text from the `EditText`, before calling `execute()` or `executeOnExecutor()`

Also note:

- HttpClient has not been recommended for years, was deprecated in Android 5.1, and was removed from the SDK in Android 6.0
- Using a nested class implementation of `AsyncTask` (as you are doing with `SendPostReqAsyncTask`) will result in a memory leak when the device undergoes a configuration change (e.g., the user rotates the device from portrait to landscape)

Answer (score 0):

`doInBackground` method does not runs on the UI(main) thread, so you cannot update or use `getText()` from there. But good news is, you can do that processing in `onPostExecute()` method.

**EDIT**

A good option could be, fetching the value of your editText before AsyncTask, and then send it to your SendPostReqAsyncTask constructor.

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: @CommonsWare : How is your answer different from mine?

Comment: You edited your answer after I wrote my comment and after I wrote my answer. My comment was for your original answer, which did not address the concerns outlined in the question.

Comment: By the time, I was editing my answer,  your answer was not visible, but its okay my answer was incomplete, that's why I edited.